# PowerBuilder application execution error R0030

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, powerbuilder

I'm running into an issue where were we built an application in PowerBuilder 12.6, and I can run the application just fine on multiple client machines.  However, I'm running into an issue where when we try to run it from a Windows 2008 R2 Server I receive the following message:

"PowerBuilder application execution error(R0030): Application terminated. Error: Cannot find data type u_main at line 73 in ue_load_scripts event of object w_main"

Yet I can run this on the 2008 client machine without error.  Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made menu changes recently?  That is an error I have seen when menus and descendants of those menus haven't been regenerated after changes.

Try a regen of all the associated menus and a full rebuild if that doesn't work.  Also make sure that your menu setting of allowing dashes "-" is consistent with your other setup.

Good Luck
G2

Comment: Why would I get this error message on one database but not another?  Could it be some sort of permissions issue?